# How to open Gradle project in Android Studio (fixing "gradle sync fails error") - error in opening zip file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have been trying to run my project using the android emulator but everytime i try i get an error:

```
error reading C:\Users\ASUS\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\34085af895daa23049fd0af188e6a001\drawerlayout-1.0.0\jars\classes.jar; error in opening zip file
```

I have been trying to build the gradle but it always fails to sync

I want to be able to build the gradle and run the program using the emulator

Comment: 1730 results show up when I paste gradle sync fails into the search bar for this site. Could you see if someone has already answered the question?

Comment: I searched but for this specific error i was unable to find an answer, i even tried answers that remotely was related to the error but still was unable to find an answer

Comment: A couple of things may help this question. The version of Android Studio and the environment you are using. Also a precise indication of what you have tried in the question. Not all readers will go through the comments. The FAQs of the site cover how to improve your question. You can edit it to include the items tried so folks don't offer up answers that will not fit your situation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the .jar file, download another one manually and replace it in the same directory. I'm not sure, but this might help.

Comment: But what is the .jar file?